# Linq - Retrieving data for a period of time (7 days), i.e. Order Count for Graph

Tags: linq, entity-framework, datetime, kendo-dataviz

Firstly, I've found a solution to my problem. The question is - is there a better way?

I needed to retrieve a list of Order counts for a period (7 days), such as using a group by. On some days there are no orders, which would mean those days would be eliminated from a group by.

This is what I needed to achieve (using a Kendo UI bar chart):

[image: A graph of orders for the last 7 days, some days with 0 orders]

I've done this in 2 stages. The first to create an Enumeration of the days, then secondly to retrieve the count of Orders from the database.

Notes: 
**db** is an Entity Framework data context.
**DbFunctions.TruncateTime()** is used to compare only the date, ignoring the time part).

```
var from = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6);
var to = DateTime.Now;

var days = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + to.Subtract(from).Days)
            .Select(offset => from.AddDays(offset))
            .ToArray();

var data = days
           .Select(i => new
           {
                Day = i.ToShortDateString(),
                Orders = db.Orders.Count(d => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.OrderDate) == i.Date)
            });
```

Can it be done better? To retrieve a count/sum of items over the last 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. The idea is firstly filter for all Orders having `OrderDate` in range, then to fill up the missing OrderDate we can use `Concat` to append some default Dates (in range). Next we use `GroupBy` and `OrderBy` to prepare for projection. Finally we project it normally but note that `g.Count()` should be decreased by `1` because we appended all default Dates (making orders of each Date be increased by 1).

```
var data = db.Orders.Select(o => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.OrderDate))
                    .Where(d => DbFunctions.DiffDays(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now), d) < 7)
                    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0,7).Select(i => DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-i) as DateTime?))       
                    .GroupBy(d => d)
                    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                    .Select(g => new {
                                 Day = g.Key.ToShortDateString(),
                                 Orders = g.Count() - 1
                             });
```

Comment: This will not work since GroupBy with eleminate dates with no orders. see 21/08/2015 & 25/08/2015 in graph.

Comment: @Nikita yes I misread the question. After that I've tried finding a work-around and ended up with an updated answer.

Comment: Enumerable has time part ,so currently I might get two records ,one for 25/08/2015 & another for 25/08/2015 15:50:00.Also, why we need to "- 1" from the count?

Comment: @Nikita in Enumerable, I used `DateTime.Now.Date` not just `DateTime.Now` so the time part should be removed. As I explained, the `Concat` makes orders count of each Date be increased by 1. So at the end we have to subtract 1 (then the missing Dates will have orders count = 0).

Answer (score 0):

This solution has a major problem that you are querying db.Orders each time, that can be expensive if Order has thousands of records.
Yes, there is a better way:

```
var orderDictionary= (from ord in db.Orders
                     let dateOfOrder=DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ord.OrderDate)
                     where dateOfOrder>=fromDate && dateOfOrder<=toDate 
                     group by dateOfOrder into ordGrp
                  select new {Key=ordGrp.Key,Count=ordGrp.Count()}).ToDictionary(o=>o.Key,o=>o.Count);

var data=days.Select(i=>new
                     {   Day=i.ToShortDateString(), 
                         NoOfOrders=orderDictionary.ContainsKey(i.Date)?orderDictionary[i.Date]:null
                     });
```